# Hiding error messages using angularjs watchCollection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have two forms in a separate accordion. The first form is an individual information form and the other one is a company information form. Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1">

<section class="basic-info">
    <div class="heading text-center">
        <h1>Basic Information</h1>
        <p>Register as an individual OR as a company</p>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="custom-accordion">
        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

            <accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen">
                <accordion-heading>
                    Individual Information<i class="pull-right" ng-class="{'fa fa-angle-down': status.isFirstOpen, 'fa fa-angle-right': !status.isFirstOpen}"></i>
                </accordion-heading>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-disabled="(user.company_name.length > 0 || user.company_number > 0) && (SignUpForm.company_number.$dirty || SignUpForm.company_name.$dirty) " class="form-control input-md" ng-model="user.first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-messages="SignUpForm.first_name.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.first_name.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">
                            <span>Please enter first name</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-disabled="(user.company_name.length > 0 || user.company_number > 0) && (SignUpForm.company_number.$dirty || SignUpForm.company_name.$dirty) " class="form-control input-md" ng-model="user.last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-messages="SignUpForm.last_name.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.last_name.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">
                           <span>Please enter your last name</span>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Salutation</label>
                            <select class="form-control input-md" ng-disabled="(user.company_name.length > 0 || user.company_number > 0) && (SignUpForm.company_number.$dirty || SignUpForm.company_name.$dirty)" ng-model="user.salutation" name="salutation" required>
                                <option value="">Select Salutation</option>
                                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-messages="SignUpForm.salutation.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.salutation.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">
                           <span>Please select a salutation</span>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Middle Name</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-disabled="(user.company_name.length > 0 || user.company_number > 0) && (SignUpForm.company_number.$dirty || SignUpForm.company_name.$dirty)" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="user.middle_name" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-messages="SignUpForm.middle_name.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.middle_name.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">
                           <span>Please enter your middle name</span>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </accordion-group>

            <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
                <accordion-heading>
                    Company Information<i class="pull-right" ng-class="{'fa fa-angle-down': status.open, 'fa fa-angle-right': !status.open}"></i>
                </accordion-heading> 

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Company Name</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-click"check()" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="user.company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name" required 
                            ng-disabled="(user.first_name.length > 0 || user.last_name.length > 0 || user.middle_name.length > 0 || user.salutation.length > 0) && (SignUpForm.middle_name.$dirty ||  SignUpForm.first_name.$dirty|| SignUpForm.last_name.$dirty || SignUpForm.salutation.$dirty)">
                        </div>
                        <div ng-messages="SignUpForm.company_name.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.company_name.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required" >
                           <span>Please enter a company name</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Company Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="user.company_number" name="company_number" placeholder="Company Number" required ng-disabled="(user.first_name.length > 0 || user.last_name.length > 0 || user.middle_name.length > 0 || user.salutation.length > 0) && (SignUpForm.middle_name.$dirty ||  SignUpForm.first_name.$dirty || SignUpForm.last_name.$dirty || SignUpForm.salutation.$dirty)"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-messages="SignUpForm.company_number.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.company_number.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">
                           <span>Please enter company number</span>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation-btns text-center">
        <a ui-sref="form.accountInfo" class="btn btn-info back-btn" ng-click="update(15)">Back</a>


        <a ui-sref="form.address" class="btn btn-info continue-btn" ng-click="update(31)">Save and Continue</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="separator"></div>
</section>
```

The user should only be able to fill out one of the forms and the other one should be disabled. I am using ngdisabled to accomplish this. 
Additionally, I am using $scope.$watchCollection to watch the input fields so that if the user  enters a value in at least one of 
the input fields of one of the individual information form and then decides to clear 
what they have entered and fill out the company information form instead. The error messages that are shown in individual form should have been reset to pristine
based on the following code:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('[user.company_name,user.company_number,user.first_name,user.last_name,user.middle_name,user.salutation]',function(newValue){


      //set individual form inputs to pristine
      if(newValue[0].length > 0 || newValue[1] > 0 ){
            $scope.SignUpForm.first_name.$setPristine();
            $scope.SignUpForm.last_name.$setPristine();
            $scope.SignUpForm.middle_name.$setPristine();
            $scope.SignUpForm.salutation.$setPristine();      
      }

       //set company form inputs to pristine
      if((newValue[2].length > 0) || (newValue[3].length > 0) || (newValue[4].length > 0) || (newValue[5].length > 0)){
            $scope.SignUpForm.company_name.$setPristine();
            $scope.SignUpForm.company_number.$setPristine();
       }});
```

What I have done so far partially works, the first if conditional statement block within $scope.$watchCollection should set the form 
fields of first_name, last_name, middle_name and salutation to pristine if the company name or the company number has a value.
When I enter a value into the company_name input field, any of the input fields that has an error message in the individual form got cleared.
However, if I enter a value into the company_number input field first, none of the error messages got cleared. 
The second if statement block does not even work probably either. What could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.